# Lowest string for StringComparer

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

Is there a string `a` for which `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(a,b)` returns a value < 0 for all `b` not equal to `a`?

Does a similar string `a` exist for other string cultures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `a` to `null` seems to satisfy this condition.

```
> StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(null, null)
0 // this is fine as a is equal to b
> StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(null, 'a')
-1
> StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(null, "")
-1
> StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(null, string.Empty)
-1
> StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(null, "-1")
-1
> StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(null, "-")
-1
> StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(null, "-")
-1
```

Comment: quite probably the empty string `""` too, with the advantage that `""` is a string; it does indeed look like `null < ""` for this purpose, but ... that's semantics :)